# Two airplanes depart at the same time

Tags: calculus, derivatives, word-problem

Two airplanes depart at the same time from Paris to London. One flies with a velocity of 350 km/h and the other flies with v=280 km/h. After 2 hours, the first airplane decreases its velocity with 230 km/h. At what distance from Paris does the second plane reach the first airplane?

I found after two hours that the first airplane will have done 700 km and the second will have done 560 km/h. But from then, I don't understand how we can connect the dots.

Comment: After 2 hours, the planes are 140km apart, and moving at a relative speed of 50km/h, so you should be able to figure it out from there. Also after 2 hours, the pilots will have far overshot their destination and will have to turn around - the distance from Paris to London is ~350km and takes only about an hour to fly, so if they're still going after 2 hours and 700km, they are *lost*.

Comment: At those speeds, after $2$ hours both airplanes have already reached London. That would make the answer:
$$\text{"At roughly 340 kilometers from Paris."}$$
because that is the distance from Paris to London.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your tags are incorrect - there are no links to calculus or derivatives in this problem.

After the 2 hours:

Plane 1 distance = 700 km
Plane 1 Velocity = 230 km/h

Plane 2 distance = 560
Plane 2 velocity = 280 km/h

For each hour, Plane 2 gains (280 - 230 = 50km) on Plane 1

So

Time to match Plane 1 d/s = (700-560)/50 = 2.8 hours

Therefore

distance = t x s = 2.8 x 230 = 644

644 + 700 = 1344 km from Paris (and you can check this by doing 560 + (2.8 x 280))

Hope that helps!

Comment: Firstly thank you for your input. I really appreciate it. My tags were edited by someone else apparently. Anyway, thank you again. I can see where I got stuck. Have a nice day!